# how to use destructuring in react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have done lots of reading online and just cant get destructuring into my head, well sort of.

```
//before destructuring
function me(details){
  console.log('My name is ' + details.name + ' and I work for ' + details.company);
}
//after destructuring
function me({ name, company }){
  console.log('my name is ' + name + ' and i work for ' + company);
}

me({
  name: 'Rich',
  age: 34,
  city: 'London',
  company: 'Google'
})
```

I've written this and this makes sense but one thing I dont get is the following in react.

if you do this:

`export default ({ name }) => <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>;`

`<Hello name="CodeSandbox" />`

why cant i do this:

`export default ( name ) => <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>;`

removing the `{}` in the function parameter?

if someone sees what im doing wrong please can they explain this?

im used to functions like so:

```
functionA (a) => { // do something with the parameter a }
```

not sure about the curlys `{}` inside the parameters

Comment: Because react passes the the `props` object to the component - `{ name: "asdf" }`. To get the name, you need to destructure it.

Comment: Because `<Hello name="CodeSandbox" />` is passed to the function something like `yourFunction({name:"CodeSandbox" })`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
export default (name) => <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>;
```

won't work because for any component, there is only one argument which is `props`

So in its longest form you could write

```
export default (props) => {
  return <h1>Hello {props.name}!</h1>;
}
```

which can be shortened (using destructuring) as:

```
export default (props) => {
  const {name} = props; // Extract name from props using destructuring
  return <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>;
}
```

which can be shortened (using destructuring at parameter level) as:

```
export default ({name}) => { // Extract name directly here
  return <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>;
}
```

which can be shortened (removing the function body curly braces) as:

```
export default ({name}) => <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>;
```

Comment: this is one of the all time most helpful answers, thanks!